# Flutter run on iOS Device: ERROR: Could not connect to lockdownd, error code -8

Tags: flutter

Since yesterday, when trying to build for an iOS Device, I get the following error when running `flutter run`:

```
ideviceinfo returned an error:
ERROR: Could not connect to lockdownd, error code -8
Exited (1)
```

Shortly after the iPhone glitches out completely (several features just stop working randomly), then shuts down after a few seconds before rebooting. After a reboot everything is fine again, but when I try building the app, the exact same happens.

I couldn't find anything for error code 8. Any idea what it is and how to fix it?

My SDK Version is on `v1.9.1+hotfix.6`, I'm building on macOs Catalina 10.15.1  for an iPhone Xs on iOs 13.2.2 (latest to date)

Answer (score 2):

Just the same situation, even the iPhone glitches. As said [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/24600) you mus follow these steps:

> restart computer or run
>
> - brew update
> - brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies libimobiledevice
> - brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies usbmuxd
> - brew install --HEAD usbmuxd
> - brew unlink usbmuxd
> - brew link usbmuxd
> - brew install --HEAD libimobiledevice
> - brew install ideviceinstaller